# SWRevealViewController closes when opened beyond 'snappoint'

Tags: objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to make the [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) work in my application.

What I did is I didn't want to be able to open the menu from everywhere on the screen so I changed all the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` so it would only be triggered from the side of the screen.

to achieve this I also altered the`panGestureRecognizer` method. This looks as follows right now

```
- (UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer*)panGestureRecognizer
{
    if ( _panGestureRecognizer == nil )
    {
        _panGestureRecognizer = [[SWRevealViewControllerPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(_handleRevealGesture:)];
        _panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        _panGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
        [_contentView.frontView addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return _panGestureRecognizer;
}
```

However (not sure if this change is causing my problem) when I start to open the menu from the left side and expand it over the point where it will normally snap to when opened up it will collapse back in.

so let's say it opens to 500px of the screen. When I drag it beyond those 500px it will automatically close the menu.

Also it's currently not possible to close the menu again by swiping it. What I did for now is add a gesturerecognizer which will trigger the `revealViewController.revealToggle(animated: true)` method.

Does anyone happen to know how to fix this?

Comment: I cant answer you since im not at my computer but there is a method where you can change how far you have to swipe for it to close, look through the .h file for methods, i think the method has bounce in the name but all the methods have descriptions of what they do so just look for the method in there.

Comment: @Timmy I'll try if I can find it. I thought there was only a method there to set to which point it should snap. reading objective c when you're used to swift tho. the horror haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by using the delegate methods that come with `SWRevealViewController` my entire code looks like this

```
import UIKit
import SWRevealViewController
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class ViewController: UIViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var openMenu: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        openMenu.target = self.revealViewController()
        openMenu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        revealViewController().delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        self.hideMenuWhenTappedAround()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func revealControllerPanGestureShouldBegin(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!) -> Bool {
        let point = revealController.panGestureRecognizer().location(in: self.view)

        if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.left && point.x < 50.0 {
            return true
        }
        else if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.right {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    func revealController(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!, panGestureMovedToLocation location: CGFloat, progress: CGFloat) {
        if location >= revealController.rearViewRevealWidth {
            revealController.panGestureRecognizer().state = UIGestureRecognizerState.ended
        }
    }
}
```

The `self.hideMenuWhentappedAround()` makes sure that the menu will close when you tap anywhere on the uiview. This method is created in an extension of the `UIViewController` and it looks as follows.

```
import UIKit
import SWRevealViewController

extension UIViewController {
    func hideMenuWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.dismissMenu))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissMenu() {
        self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**import `#import "SWRevealViewController.h`"**

**These two gestures helps you to open and close sw menu . Drag and click for open and close SW**

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
```

**Open sw menu normally**

```
[self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES]
```